# Missing \endcsname inserted while using \DTLloaddb

Tags: errors, datatool

I'm almost getting crazy with this TeX error, but however I can't find any effective method to solve this. Here is a mini example which cause the problem, and which i really need in my codes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% \begin{filecontents*}{emaildb.csv}
% FirstName,Surname,Email1,Email2,Reg Num
% Mary,Jones,mj@my.uni.ac.uk,mj@somewhere.com,0
% Adam,Smith,as@my.uni.ac.uk,,12345
% \end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{abc.csv}
Zeit/s,AMES\_13,AMES\_14,AMES\_15,AMES\_16
"3,0",000,"8,760V","0,000","0,216mA"
"6,0",000,"13,120V","0,000","0,169mA"
"9,0",000,"16,550V","0,000","0,132mA"
"12,0",000,"19,660V","0,000","0,103mA"
"15,0",000,"21,730V","0,000","0,081mA"
"18,0",000,"23,580V","0,000","0,066mA"
"21,0",000,"24,850V","0,000","0,052mA"
"24,0",000,"25,980V","0,000","0,041mA"
"27,0",000,"26,740V","0,000","0,033mA"
"30,0",000,"27,420V","0,000","0,026mA",
"33,0",000,"27,890V","0,000","0,021mA"
"36,0",000,"28,300V","0,000","0,017mA"
"39,0",000,"28,590V","0,000","0,014mA"
"42,0",000,"28,820V","0,000","0,012mA"
"45,0",000,"29,020V","0,000","0,010mA"
"48,0",000,"29,150V","0,000","0,009mA"
"51,0",000,"29,280V","0,000","0,008mA"
"54,0",000,"29,360V","0,000","0,007mA"
"57,0",000,"29,430V","0,000","0,006mA"
"60,0",000,"29,490V","0,000","0,006mA"
"63,0",000,"29,520V","0,000","0,005mA"
"66,0",000,"29,560V","0,000","0,005mA"
"69,0",000,"29,580V","0,000","0,004mA"
"72,0",000,"29,610V","0,000","0,004mA"
"75,0",000,"29,630V","0,000","0,004mA"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{ddb}{abc.csv}
\end{document}
```

However if I comment `filecontents` for `emaildb.csv` and change `\DTLloaddb{ddb}{emaildb.csv}` I get no error then. It means then, that theres something wrong in `abc.cvs` but, I have also reentered it, making sure theres no strange invisible characters in it, but it still says `Missing \endscname inserted` :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is the use of active characters in the database headers.

When loading a database using `\DTLloaddb`, [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) suggests to consider using the key

> **`autokeys`**
>
> This is a boolean option that will automatically assign default 
>   keys [..] for all columns, regardless
>   of whether the file has a header row. If true, this option overrides
>   the keys option. You may want to use this if you have a header row
>   with many fields containing active characters but you only want to
>   use commands like `\DTLdisplaydb`. (In which case, you may
>   want to consider using `\DTLloadrawdb` to load the data.)

The second suggestion is to consider loading the database using

> **`\DTLloadrawdb`**
>
> This is the same as `\DTLloaddb` except that it maps nine of the ten
>   special characters onto commands which produce that symbol. The only
>   character that retains its active state is the backslash character, so you will
>   still need to check the file for backslash characters. The mappings used
>   are [..]
>
> ```
> %  ->  \%
> $  ->  \$
> &  ->  \&
> #  ->  \#
> _  ->  \_
> {  ->  \{
> }  ->  \}
> ~  ->  \textasciitilde
> ^  ->  \textasciicircum
> ```

...or define your own mapping via `\DTLrawmap{<string>}{<replacement>}`.

The suggestion would be to avoid using active characters in the database (unless it's *really* needed) and/or use a combination of the `keys` and `headers` keys:

> **`keys`**
>
> This is a comma-separated list of keys to use, where the keys are
>   listed in the same order as the columns. If the file has a header,
>   these keys will override the values given in the header row. If the
>   file has no header row and no keys are supplied in `<options>`, then
>   the keys will be given by `\dtldefaultkey<n>`, where `<n>` is the
>   `\dtldefaultkey` column number and `\dtldefaultkey` defaults to “Column”.
>   Note that the list of keys must be delimited by braces since they
>   contain commas.
>
> **`headers`**
>
> This is a comma-separated list of headers. If not supplied, the
>   header will be the same as that given in the header row, or the key
>   if there is no header row. Note that the list of headers must be
>   delimited by braces since they contain commas.

For example, using

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abc.csv}
first,second,third,fourth,fifth
"3,0",000,"8,760V","0,000","0,216mA"
..
```

and then load it using

```
\DTLloaddb[
  keys = {first,second,third,fourth,fifth},
  headers = {Zeit/s,AMES\_13,AMES\_14,AMES\_15,AMES\_16}
]{ddb}{abc.csv}
```

Answer (score 2):

`datatool` tries to make command names out of the items in the first row, but `\_` is not legal in the construction that allows this.

The best would be avoiding special characters, but the good news is that not escaping `_` works.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{abc.csv}
Zeit/s,AMES_13,AMES_14,AMES_15,AMES_16
"3,0",000,"8,760V","0,000","0,216mA"
"6,0",000,"13,120V","0,000","0,169mA"
```

This *may* produce problems later on, if you want to print those headers. If you find such problems, please, update your question.